Declaring JSON values as null by default
I've got a python API with POST method which has an input JSON structured like this:
{
  "foo": 0,
  "bar": 0,
  "baz": "string",
}

But these default values are not the ones that work for me.
The desired default JSON would have a null value applied to every field, just like this:
{
  "foo": null,
  "bar": null,
  "baz": null,
}

Using Pydantic Field(example=None) or Field(default=None) has not helped me at all.
I am not aware of FastAPI functions or attributes that would help me achieve my goal.

Can you use a dictionary with values of None as the default?

@JonSG apparently not, giving a dict with values populated as None to the FastAPI method makes the JSON disappear, leaving only an empty dict to populate.

actual_parameters = {**default, **passed} where default is you dictionary of default keys and values.

Do you have the code that makes up your actual endpoint and models, and what your request looks like?

To allow a default null value, you need to add it to the definition of your field.
You didn't share it in the original message, so I created this working example:
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(title="App")


class PostRequestExample(BaseModel):
    foo: int | None = None
    bar: int | None = None
    buz: str | None = None


@app.post('/post_example')
async def post_example(post_request: PostRequestExample):

    return post_request

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(
        "post_example:app"
    )

